# How to disable assets combining on development in OctoberCMS

Tags: php, octobercms

October CMS offers handy functionality to combine js/css assets. In my `layouts/default.htm` I have scripts defined like that:

```
<script src="{{ [
    'assets/javascript/jquery.js',
    'assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/transition.js',
    'assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/alert.js',
    'assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/button.js',
    'assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/carousel.js',
    'assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/collapse.js',
    'assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/dropdown.js',
    'assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/modal.js',
    'assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/tooltip.js',
    'assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/popover.js',
    'assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/scrollspy.js',
    'assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/tab.js',
    'assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/affix.js',
    'assets/javascript/app.js',
    '@framework',
    '@framework.extras'
]|theme }}"></script>
{% scripts %}
```

In the `config/cms.php` file I have:

```
'enableAssetCache' => false,
'enableAssetMinify' => null,
```

And in the `config/app.php`:

```
'debug' => true,
```

This results in the combining of all scripts defined in the twig array. On the rendered website I get one javascript file

```
<script src="http://localhost/Test/october/combine/2cdc17b704821cd2ffbd9be8e4d340f9-1457016128"></script>
```

I would like to have an option to NOT combine my assets as long as the `'debug' => true` is enabled in `config/app.php` (so in the development environment).

I know that I can have my assets served separately by October CMS if I add them to my layout in separate script tags. But this would serve them separately on production as well. Example:

```
<script src="{{ 'assets/js/one.js'|theme }}"></script>
<script src="{{ 'assets/js/two.js'|theme }}"></script>
```

I have found this 1.5 year old issue on github with no useful answer:
https://github.com/octobercms/october/issues/289

And documentation also says nothing useful about this matter:
https://octobercms.com/docs/markup/filter-theme

Do you have any idea how to deal with this? I have though maybe that I can create a plugin in OctoberCMS, which will inject assets to the layout depending on the config setting (debug true/false). But as far as I know injecting assets from within the plugin, require to have the assets in the **plugin directory** and not **theme directory**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I managed to work this out but not with the `config/app.php` mentioned in the question.

Other solution requires to create `.env` file in the root directory of OctoberCMS. This file is by default in the `.gitignore` so you can have different .env files on production and development ([Piece of documentation](http://octobercms.com/docs/setup/configuration#environment-config))

Contents of this file should be:

```
APP_ENV=dev
```

Then you can access variable in the twig:

```
{% if this.environment == 'dev' %}
    <script src="{{ 'assets/vendor/jquery.min.js'|theme }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ 'assets/semantic/dist/semantic.min.js'|theme }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ 'assets/javascript/app.js' | theme }}"></script>
    {% framework extras %}
{% else %}
    <script src="{{ [
     'assets/vendor/jquery.js',
     'assets/semantic/dist/semantic.js',
     'assets/javascript/app.js',
     '@framework',
     '@framework.extras'
     ]|theme }}"></script>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try switching **off** this in your config file **(app/config/cms.php)**

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Determines if the asset minifcation is enabled.
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If the minifcation is enabled, combined assets are compressed (minified).
| It is recommended to disable the minification during the development, and
| enable it in the production mode.
|
*/

'enableAssetMinify' => true,
```

Comment: op was asking for disabling of combiner and not the minification